# what is the best way for reference id of child object in parent object in mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I have 2 objects;

**board.rb**

```
class Board
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :posts, :autosave => true, dependent: :destroy
  field :collected, :type => Array, :default => []
end
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :board
end
```

**In addition** to the relationship that is created by default, I want to create a field in which to store or reference the posts in the parent object (**Board**).

Is it possible to create a reference without needs to duplicate the object? As well as the relationship that is created by default? What is the optimal way to do it?

Create an array field (**collected field**) and enter the ids of all the posts or is there a better way?

I do not want duplicate objects, I just want to have a reference of the original objects and after I want find this object with a **where** query or **find** query.

How can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you need post_ids in board?

Comment: I want a user to collect the original post on their boards. I do not want to make a copy of the object on the board of each user. Instead I just want to reference the original post on the board of the users who will collect the post.

Comment: I still do not understand why you need them, but resetting post_ids with `self.post_ids = Post.where(:board_id => self.id).only(:_id).map(&:_id)` will be better than what you are doing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Board` objects will respond to `posts` with an array. If you want an array of only the ID's of the referenced objects call: `board.posts.collect {|p| p.id}`. If you need to use this often, you can define a method in your model that returns it.